# unreachable statement trying to set up a button that will open a new activity

Tags: java, android, button, android-activity, unreachable-statement

Im very much new to this. I have a quick question. I get an "unreachable statement on line 30 (establecimientos = findViewById(R.id.establecimientos) while trying to set up that button to take me to a new activity. Can you help pointing at what is wrong, thank you ?

This is what my my java looks like:

```js
package com.example.ceibasxi;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.widget.Button;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar;


public class PaginaDos extends AppCompatActivity {
    Button establecimientos;
    Button servicios;
    Button productos;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_pagina_dos);

        Toolbar myToolbar = findViewById(R.id.my_toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(myToolbar);
    }

    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_appbar, menu);
        return true;


establecimientos = findViewById(R.id.establecimientos);
establecimientos.setOnClickListener(v -> {

servicios = findViewById(R.id.servicios);
servicios.setOnClickListener(v1 -> {
Intent intent1 = new Intent(PaginaDos.this, PaginaServicios.class);
startActivity(intent1);

productos = findViewById(R.id.producto);
productos.setOnClickListener(v11 -> {
Intent intent2 = new Intent(PaginaDos.this, PaginaProductos.class);
startActivity(intent2);}

);});})
    ;}}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your code you have the following:

```
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_appbar, menu);
    return true;
```

You have a lot of code after this that will never be executed in the method `onCreateOptionsMenu()` because you have a `return` statement. Nothing after the `return` statement will be executed in this method.

It looks to me like this code should be inside the `onCreate()` method instead of inside the `onCreateOptionsMenu()` method.

Perhaps you've simply moved code around and gotten confused.